# How to resolve the maven dependency issue

Tags: maven, aem

when i tried to deploy my maven project into AEM 6.2 bundle remains in install state and its shows the following error

com.day.cq.commons,version=[5.7,6) -- Cannot be resolved
com.day.cq.replication,version=[5.15,6) -- Cannot be resolved

need help!!!

Comment: Are `com.day.cq.commons version 5.7` and `com.day.cq.replication version 5.15` in your `.m2` directory (or where ever you keep your dependencies)?

Comment: @DovahkiinvasNormandy Tried the same but didn't worked

Comment: @BajjuriKarthik - What does your pom.xml look like?  Are you using the uber-jar dependency?  If not, do you have dependencies listed for these?

Comment: Make sure the version of the jar that you've specified as a dependency in the pom is available in your AEM 6.2 runtime,

Comment: @Bajjuri, it would be great if you can provide your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Following is available in AEM 6.2 and that's what your POM should reflect -

For CQ Commons

```
<groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
<artifactId>cq-commons</artifactId>
<version>5.9.22</version>
```

For CQ Replication

```
<groupId>com.adobe.granite</groupId>
<artifactId>com.adobe.granite.replication.core</artifactId>
<version>6.0.14</version>
```